# Sending Guzzle request to itemize api

Tags: http, request, guzzle

**The situation:**

I need to send the request to the api to update the account info.
The API docs say I need to do send a PUT request to the API. 
I trying to do this in Laravel 5.6, although I don't think this matters.

**What I have so far:**

A working constructor for the Guzzle client;
A working function to retrieve account info.

**What is not working:**

Upon submitting the request I get a Guzzle exception

```
Client error: \`PUT https://sandbox.proapi.itemize.com/api/enterprise/v1/accounts/<my account id>\` resulted in a \`400 Bad Request\` response: IOException:
```

This is the code I have so far:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\GuzzleException;

class ApiController extends Controller {

    private $apiKey;
    private $uri;
    private $client;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->apiKey = 'my api key';
        $this->uri = 'https://sandbox.proapi.itemize.com/api/enterprise/v1/accounts/my account id';
        $this->client = new Client([
            'base_uri' => $this->uri,
            'auth' => [null, $this->apiKey]]);
    }

    public function accountInfo() {
        $response = $this->client->request('GET','');
        echo $response->getBody()->getContents();
    }

    public function updateAccountInfo() {
        $response = $this->client->request('PUT','',[
            'headers' => [
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            ],
            'body' => '{"markets":"UK"}'
        ]);
        echo $response->getBody()->getContents();
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`400 Bad Request` means: request sent by the client due to invalid syntax.

According [itemize api documentation](https://apidocs.itemize.com/enterprise/#accounts) "markets" should be passed as an array of strings. And you can also use [json](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#json) format.

Try this:

```
public function updateAccountInfo() {
    $response = $this->client->request('PUT', '', [
        'json' => ["markets" => ["UK"]],
    ]);
    echo $response->getBody()->getContents();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Tried it, still didn't work. At this point I am assuming their api doc is useless and have emailed their CS. I actually had to do trying to simply get the account info at first, as it was not authorizing me. I received a response from their rep that they talked to their technical team and it should be working now. And it was! I'm simply a little affraid of the mess I'm  getting myself into if I will have to wait for them to "fix" every single thing in their doc.

Comment: Another thing - I have tried using curl on cli and just copy pasted their sample code with email and contact data - still got a bad request. Everything really is pointing to a fault on their end.